# ThreeJs Loads more vertices than there are in an obj file

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have this code:

```
function render_obj(objPath){
  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  loader.load(
    objPath,
    function ( object ) {
      child = object.children[0];
      var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( child.geometry );      
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: true});
      model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(model);
    },
    function ( xhr ) {
      console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
    },
    function ( error ) {
      console.log( 'An error happened' );
    }
  );
};
```

now `man.obj` has 214 vertices and 332 faces. When I check the faces by doing this: `model.geometry.faces.length` I get 332 which is correct.
When I do `model.geometry.vertices.length` I get 996, where I should get 214...

Why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loader that you are using is creating something called “triangle soup”. This means that your N triangles are actually defined by N * 3 vertices. A triangle itself doesn't really exist, it's just interpreted from the vertices. The first three make a triangle, the next three and so on. If you have a continuous smooth mesh, a lot of vertices will be duplicated.

What you are probably interested in is “indexed” geometry. In this type of geometry, you have an actual triangle buffer holding the index is for the vertices. In a continuous smooth mesh, one vertex can be shared by many triangles.

Comment: Maybe add some information on how to get an indexed geometry. Did the OP end up with "triangle soup" because of how the model was exported from the 3d app as an .obj?

Comment: I believe the .obj loader is the culprit, i thought obj will always export with indices but i'm not sure. Also if that is the case, there isn't really a fix short of modifying the loader? The original question asks specifically what happened, not how to fix it, but ill be happy to edit my response (although this comment might be enough?).

Comment: Thanks for the answer I found 'geometry.mergeVertices(); ' to do the trick for me. from here https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry.mergeVertices

Comment: @pailhead, I was just curious and thought it would probably add value to the answer

Comment: The only problem you might have is if you merge vertices where there should be a "hard edge" hard edge means there need to be duplicated normal at a single vertex, and then even with indexed geometry you have to duplicate vertices. On a cube, a face pointing left would have one vertex with a normal pointing left, the adjoint face pointing up would have another vertex with a normal pointing up. Both vertices would have the same values but they need to be duplicated. The obj should hold this information but its lost when converted to triangle soup.